# Remote access to pc in a LAN: how to connect to an individual pc

Tags: dynamic-ip

I've installed a dynamic DNS client which points at my account on noip.com.

it works.I type the host-name (which i registered with noip) into the address bar of a browser on a pc outside of my LAN and it takes me to my routers current IP.

This only takes me to the routers configuration page (which of course is what is expected).

how do i make it (my host-name/address) redirect to an individual pc in the LAN??

My Laptop: Ubuntu 12.04 LTS
my DDns client: noip's own client, downloaded from the noip website

Thanksssss

Answer (score 0):

Portforwarding on your router. If you want http to be forwarded
set port 80 to your laptops ip or hostname port 80.